# loadNibNamed - Could not load NIB in bundle: NSBundle

Tags: objective-c, drop-down-menu, uitableview, xcode4.3

I'm trying to create a TableViewCell, using a XIB file, but I get this error at execution time:

> 2013-01-10 17:54:50.297 MainApp[6778:b603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'DropDownCell'' 
>
>   *** Call stack at first throw:

This is what I'm trying to do.
I have a project, with a first Menu. In this project/workspace, I have the class for my first Menu. Inside this project, I have another workspace, with the classes for my second Menu. I mean, this workspace is for the SubViewController's and classes for the options selected in my first Menu. In this workspace, I'm trying to create a DropDownMenu,using the demo from apple, but my app crash. This demo creates the cell's in the table, using a XIB file.
This is the DropDownCell class:
**DropDownCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DropDownCell : UITableViewCell{
  IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;
  IBOutlet UIImageView *arrow_up;
  IBOutlet UIImageView *arrow_down;

  BOOL isOpen;
}

-(void)setOpen;
-(void)setClosed;

@property (nonatomic)BOOL isOpen;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel *textLabel;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *arrow_up;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *arrow_down;

@end
```

**DropDownCell.m**
    #import "DropDownCell.h"

```
@implementation DropDownCell

@synthesize textLabel, arrow_up, arrow_down, isOpen;

-(void)setOpen{
   [arrow_down setHidden:YES];
   [arrow_up setHidden:NO];
   [self setIsOpen:YES];
}

-(void)setClosed{
   [arrow_down setHidden:NO];
   [arrow_up setHidden:YES];
   [self setIsOpen:NO];
}

-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier{
   self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
   if(self){

   }
   return self;
}

-(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated{
   [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}

-(void)dealloc{
   [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

And the **DropDownCell.xib** has one UITableViewCell with a UILabel.
I have another UITableViewController, which uses the DropDownCell XIB. This is the method:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MenuCell";
  static NSString *DropDownCellIdentifier = @"DropDownCell";

  if([indexPath row] == 0){
      DropDownCell *cell = (DropDownCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DropDownCellIdentifier];

      if(cell == nil){
          NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"DropDownCell" owner:self options:nil];

          for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
            if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[DropDownCell class]]){
                cell = (DropDownCell*)currentObject;
                break;
            }
          }
      }

      [[cell textLabel] setText:@"Option 1"];

      return cell;

}
```

But my app crashes when loads the NIB file... What can be the reason? I'm using Xcode 4.3, and I'm not using storyboards.

Answer (score 1):

@user1600801, There may be one of these reasons:-

1) Disable/Uncheck "Use Autolayout" in File Inspector for that Custom cell.

2) Your Target is not set for that Custom Cell.

> > To set it select your custom cell .Xib file,
> >
> > Select "File Inspector",
> >
> > Under "Target membership" check if your project name is selected? If not, Then check/enable it.

3) Check your Custom Cell class name and Cell identifiers.

Comment: Also in attributes inspector make sure the identity of the prototype cell is set to "DropDownCell"

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Auto Layout enabled for that NIB, and are compiling for

Comment: I don't understand whats or how to have the Auto Layout :S... At my XIB file, in the File Inspector -> Target Membership, I have selected my Target...

Comment: On that very same File Inspector tab, in the "Interface Builder Document" section, you have a small checkbox which says "Use Autolayout". If it is checked, your application will crash on iOS versions older than 6.0.

Comment: I don't have that "checkbox". I just have: Document Versioning: Deployment->Project SDK Version (iOS 4.3), Development->Interface Builder 3.0 | Localization Locking: Default->Nothing

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not even loading the bundle. See this question:

[NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722461/nsinternalinconsistencyexception-reason-could-not-load-nib-in-bundle-nsbun)

It seems like you can sort it out by just removing files from your project and put again there.

Comment: I get the same error....  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSBundle loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:]... Also, I get this warning...  "NSBundle may not respond to -loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObject"...

Comment: I edited it later, in the second part of the answer you see the reason of the warning.

Comment: I tried to use "inithWithNibName", but also crashes and I also get a warning, because "UITableViewCell" doesn't implement "initWithNibName

Comment: What I've said is to use a UIViewController. Inside the view controller you also load the UITableViewCell.

Comment: So, I need to create another ViewController, like DropDownViewController. With this DropDownViewController, have a XIB file, with a View, with my UITableViewCell? And load my DropDownViewController in my table, instead of load DropDownCell?

Comment: And load DropDownViewController not in the table, with the initWithNibName method inside the class itself. Even if technically you can do it both ways, but I think the one I suggest is easier.

Comment: I see that you're missing basics, join the chatroom I've created: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22552/uiviewcontroller-load-a-nib-file

Comment: i can 't join to the chatroom. It says that I don't have 20 in reputation

Comment: I deleted DropDownCell.xib and create again and still have the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the references of the nib file and clean the project.
Then add the nib file back to the project and build.
This resolves the same exception happened in my project.