# Unfortunately terminating app due to uncaught exception?

Tags: ios

I am  develop a sample app with multiple xib files and trying to make a navigate, first view to second unfortunately app has crashed

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'ViewController'

What is the reason? some code that I used:

```
#import "ViewController.h"   /*current view*/
#import "secondViewController.h"  /*view for navigate*/

-(void)navigation{
     secondViewController *desController=[[secondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
     [self presentViewController:desController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: See:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415252/nsinternalinconsistencyexception-could-not-load-nib-in-bundle
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025487/terminating-app-due-to-uncaught-exception-nsinternalinconsistencyexception-re

Answer (score 0):

i think you pass wrong name in initWithNibName:@"ViewController" that cause the error.

Comment: yes it's just a nib name mistake, thanks for guidance

Answer (score 0):

According to crash log, problem with **nib name**. Instead `oneViewControllerl`, nib name may be `oneViewController`. Check with nib(xib) file & Fixed correct nib name.

Answer (score 0):

Cross check if you are setting correct Nib name instead of `ViewController`?

```
secondViewController *desController=[[secondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
```