# UITableViewCell assignment causing Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1 error in xCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, multithreading, uitableview, breakpoints

I've looked at several other questions from people having the same problem but none of the solutions have fixed my problem. I have removed all breakpoints other than Exception breakpoints, so I can't really say I know what is going on.

Here is the code:
[image: code with error]

And here is what the Debug Navigator reports:
[image: error]

Comment: Do you get any error message when you continue from the exception breakpoint?

Comment: It is a good practice on SO to post code using the code formatting provided by the editor instead of screenshots.

Comment: I get an NSInternalInconsistencyException

Comment: Post the actual error message.

Comment: 2014-05-10 16:05:54.976 FinalProject[15650:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/mikedurante/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/0C9E3988-DCF8-4B98-A8A4-81990A7626C7/FinalProject.app> (loaded)' with name 'AssignmentCell''
*** First throw call stack:
....
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an instance of your `AssignmentCell` class if the dequeued instance is null. Add a check for null at the line where you have the exception. If the cell is null, alloc & init it there.

**EDIT** - After looking at your error message, it looks like your app attempts to load the NIB file for the table view cell and fails to do so. If you have a NIB defined for the table view cell, make sure you have it included in the project properly. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025487/terminating-app-due-to-uncaught-exception-nsinternalinconsistencyexception-re) is an example of a similar problem.

Comment: I tried doing this and the check isn't even reached because the above line causes it to crash.