# Skydrive login in iPhone App crashes

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, onedrive

I'm developing an app where I have integrated sky drive framework. But when I try to login my app crashes with:

`uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException`

Reason:

`Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/`

Using the "LiveSDK/Library" it works fine but the library does not work with ARC.
What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
(void)signInMethod { 
self.liveClient =
[[LiveConnectClient alloc] initWithClientId:APP_CLIENT_ID 
                                                     delegate:self 
                                                    userState:@"initialize"]; 
}

-(void)authCompleted:(LiveConnectSessionStatus) status 
          session:(LiveConnectSession *) session 
        userState:(id) userState { if ([userState isEqual:@"initialize"]) {
    [self.liveClient login:self 
                    scopes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"wl.signin", nil] 
                  delegate:self 
                 userState:@"signin"];

} if ([userState isEqual:@"signin"]) {
    if (session != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"signed in");      
    }
     } }

-(void)authFailed:(NSError *) error 
     userState:(id)userState { NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]]);  }
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message basically says that you have a ViewController that is trying to load a NIB file, but it cannot find it because it either is not included in the resources or it has a different name than expected.

The full error message should contain the name of the file - as you did not post it I can't know for sure, but `LiveAuthDialog_iPad`or `LiveAuthDialog_iPhone` might be missing here, those are the only .xib files I've found used by the LiveSDK.

Remove the reference to the .xib file and re-add it to your project (if it exists), otherwise add it to your project. Then Clean and Build again.

(see also: [Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19025487/terminating-app-due-to-uncaught-exception-nsinternalinconsistencyexception-re))

**Update (see comments):**

In case the compiled library version (`'LiveSDK.framework'`) is used (instead of importing the LiveSDK sources), the framework expects to be included in the app bundle's `Resources` folder, either by adding it to the `Copy Bundle Resources` build phase of the host project, or by adding it to a `Copy Files Build Phase` with the destination set to `Resources`.

The placement is important b/c the LiveSDK's [`-[LiveAuthRequest authorize]`](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-iOS/blob/8d081e2a0ee58d1ebc4b7f08529a31c66ed14c26/src/LiveSDK/Library/Internal/LiveAuthRequest.m#L171) method will primarily try to load the NIB files for the authentication dialog from the framework bundle (using [`-[LiveAuthHelper getSDKBundle]`](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-iOS/blob/master/src/LiveSDK/Library/Internal/Helpers/LiveAuthHelper.m#L34)), expecting the framework to be found inside the main bundle's resources:

```
+ (NSBundle *) getSDKBundle
{
    NSString *sdkPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"LiveSDK"
                                                        ofType:@"framework"];
    return (sdkPath)? [NSBundle bundleWithPath:sdkPath] : [NSBundle mainBundle];
}
```

Comment: There is a file called LiveAuthDialog_iPhone.nib in LiveSDK.Framework/Resources. How can I make my application use it? In my application, the code that try to login is not ViewController, it is NSObject class, I'm using UINavigationController.visibleViewController for the login first parameter.

Comment: Did you add the LiveSDK.framework to your project's "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase?

Comment: Great, happy to help! :) Please remember to mark the answer you found most helpful as accepted as that will also help others encountering the same problem. Cheers

Comment: mvanallen - can you add your comment as an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: RGregg - you're right, I've updated the answer accordingly; thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

YOU NEED TO REGISTER YOUR NIB FILE IN ViewDidLoad. If its tableViewCell then use below code
[self.tableView registerNib: withCellIndentifier];

You you are trying to load View nib then 
YourViewController *myview = [UIViewController alloc] initWithNib:];

If the nib file is itself missing then to to Target-> build phase-> Copy bundle resource and add your missing nib file