# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I get the error in the title while trying to change the text of a label which is part of the Page class (a subclass of UIViewController)

```
@IBAction func StartButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    for quote in quoteList {

        var newPage = Page()
        //error is on the next line:
        newPage.Label.text = quote

        pageArray!.append(newPage)
    }

}
```

}

and here is the Page class:

```
class Page : UIViewController{

var index: Int = 0

var parent: PageArray?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!


@IBAction func previousButton(sender: AnyObject) {
}


@IBAction func gotoListButton(sender: AnyObject) {
}


@IBAction func nextButton(sender: AnyObject) {
}
```

}

I am new when it comes to swift programming, and iOs in general; I apologise if a similar question has already been asked. I searched first, but didn't find a solution that worked for me.
I suspect the problem is with the initialization of  newPage, and tried doing it a few different ways, but I can't seem to get it right.
My question is what exactly am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

EDIT: Got it working like this (by working I mean not crashing and doing nothing):

```
    @IBAction func StartButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    var pageArray: PageArray = PageArray()

    for quote in quoteList {

        var newPage = Page(nibName: "Page", bundle: nil)


        if newPage.Label != nil {
        newPage.Label.text = quote
        }

        pageArray.append(newPage)

    }

}
```

It seems certain now that newPage.Label is nil.

Comment: I have the same problem.  I tried removing weak from @IBOutlet but that doesn't help.  However all the non-IBOutlet vars (e.g. index, parent, etc) are accessible.  It has to do with how these objects are instantiated (or not) from the storyboard/XIB file.  Still digging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `pageArray` is probably nil and with `!` you are pretending that it is not.

Instantiating pageArray should solve your issue.

You can check the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018327/what-does-an-exclamation-mark-mean-in-the-swift-language) to learn more about question and exclamation marks in swift

**EDIT**:

Your problem might also come from your controller initialization, you might want to try:

```
let mystoryboard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "storyboardName", bundle: nil)
var newPage:Page = mystoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("idYouAssigned") as! Page
```

Comment: That may be a problem, but it isn't the only one.
I am getting the error before that, on this line:
newPage.Label.text = quote

Comment: @Xebeq Do you have a xib file linked to PageView ? If so i believe it is not loaded and `Label` is always nil. You might want to use `NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed`. If you can confirm you have a xib file i'll detail my answer

Comment: Just realized, it is a viewcontroller. Init should be made with nib name. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I tried that before. For some reason, after I do this it thinks that newPage and pageArray are both strings (??). Deleting the next two lines and writing them again fixes this, but I still get the original error in the same place.

Comment: Also, the only .xib file in my project is LaunchScreen.xib and I do not believe it is linked to PageView.

Comment: @Xebeq Do you have a storyboard ? Besides how do you initialize pageArray ?

Comment: 1.Yes, I do; 2.See Edit to original post.

Comment: @Xebeq I've edited my answer to instantiate a controller from a storyboard correctly. Please make sure that the Label is correctly linked in the storyboard to your IBOutlet as well.

Comment: Where would I see the ViewController's ID?

Comment: @Xebeq in the storyboard, if you click on your controller, in the right panel you can set the id.

Comment: Found it, but it doesn't help. Label is still nil :(

Comment: @Xebeq Have you linked it in storyboard ?

Answer (score 0):

I knew your problems. When you load a ViewController from Nib. Actually It's take a delay time until your ViewController has been loaded.

This code below help your ViewController load immediate.

```
@IBAction func StartButton(sender: AnyObject) {

var pageArray: PageArray = PageArray()

for quote in quoteList {

    var newPage = Page(nibName: "Page", bundle: nil)

    let _ = newPage.view // A trick. It's help your view load immediate

    // Your Page has been loaded.
    newPage.Label.text = quote

    pageArray.append(newPage)

}
```

Comment: This earns me another error: 
**2015-07-17 15:18:24.363 Quotes[3277:855732] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/319D819D-C653-4AAF-ADDB-0514A8F055AE/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/042EE69B-E6D2-4CEF-A2D3-B1C438533DD1/Quotes.app> (loaded)' with name 'Page''
*** First throw call stack:**

Comment: Do you try rename something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722461/nsinternalinconsistencyexception-reason-could-not-load-nib-in-bundle-nsbun

Comment: Well, nevermind. A combination of this and Justa's suggestion seems to have fixed it. No errors now, nothing's nil. Thanks! (time to move on to new exciting problems)