# Memory Leak - Instruments Log

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

I have some leaks in my App, and i tried to use Instruments (its my first time with instruments).

so at 05:29:365 i got

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in
>   bundle: 'NSBundle
>   
>   (loaded)' with name 'J3S-8n-bc0-view-ceq-kS-Ecs' and directory
>   'Main.storyboard''

here is my output, there is a leak, and i can't interpret it myself. ARC is on.

[image][image][image]

[image]

Comment: Not sure if this applicable to your project, but here's a thread dealing w/ the error you encountered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722461/nsinternalinconsistencyexception-reason-could-not-load-nib-in-bundle-nsbun

Comment: no, i know the thread, but thank you