# Segment framework make UIAlertController to crash with NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: ios, swift, segment

I follow "https://segment.com/" to implement analytics . But when I use UIAlertController to show alert with title , my app was crash!shows an error

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'screen name () must not be empty.'

I am using swift for development. I just initialise the segment in AppDelegate at didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. I am not using any of alias, group, identify, page and track calls .[image]

Comment: add an exception breakpoint & check the line where it is crashing.

Comment: Post where you call `screen:properties:options:`

Comment: @shallowThought I am not calling screen:properties:options: , In fact I am not calling any method of segment. I just had integrate segment using pod, written segment initialisation code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40525231/segment-framework-make-uialertcontroller-to-crash

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am setting title as empty string so instead of setting blank "" in title,I set tittle to nil. And It is working, App is not crashing now.