# Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle' in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a view that contains a `tableview` in my app. I use **`cellForRowAtIndexPath`** function to populate `tableview`, but it crashes sometimes and throws an error like below. It occurs rarely but I want to solve it!

**Code part :**

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{

    if (self.productViewType == ProductToShelfViewTypeShelf) {

        static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"ShelfCell";
        ShelfCellView* cell = (ShelfCellView*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray* nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ShelfCellView" owner:nil options:nil];
            for (id currentObject in nibObjects) {
                if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[ShelfCellView class]]) {
                    cell = (ShelfCellView*)currentObject;
                }
            }
            [cell initViewStyles];
        }

        Shelf* shelf = [self.shelfList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.shelf = shelf;
        [cell initView];
        return cell;
    }
    else {
        static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"ProductToShelfCell";
        ProductToShelfCellView* cell = (ProductToShelfCellView*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray* nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProductToShelfCellView" owner:nil options:nil];
            for (id currentObject in nibObjects) {
                if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[ProductToShelfCellView class]]) {
                    cell = (ProductToShelfCellView*)currentObject;
                }
            }
            [cell initViewStyles];
        }
        Product* product = [self.products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.product = product;
        [cell initView];
        return cell;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

**Stacktrace :**

```
Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/containers/Bundle/Application/B07CBD90-32C2-4F41-ADB0-11AA6422AFF3/Kitapyurdu.app> (loaded)' with name 'ProductToShelfCellView'
    Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
    0  CoreFoundation                 0x1f576e07 __exceptionPreprocess
    1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1e7d7077 objc_exception_throw
    2  CoreFoundation                 0x1f576d4d -[NSException initWithCoder:]
    3  UIKit                          0x24aa5007 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]
    4  UIKit                          0x24aa726b -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:]
    5  Kitapyurdu                     0x50321 -[ProductToShelfViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] (ProductToShelfViewController.m:429)
    6  UIKit                          0x249027fb -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:]
    7  UIKit                          0x249029e5 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:]
    8  UIKit                          0x248ef1ef -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:]
    9  UIKit                          0x24907ae1 -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:]
    10 UIKit                          0x246ad345 -[UITableView layoutSubviews]
    11 UIKit                          0x245c65d5 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
    12 QuartzCore                     0x223ec109 -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
    13 QuartzCore                     0x223e031f CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
    14 QuartzCore                     0x223e01af CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
    15 QuartzCore                     0x22370a6b CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*)
    16 QuartzCore                     0x2238f035 CA::Transaction::commit()
    17 UIKit                          0x2484891f _UIApplicationFlushRunLoopCATransactionIfTooLate
    18 UIKit                          0x24d6388f __handleEventQueue
    19 CoreFoundation                 0x1f532c8b __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
    20 CoreFoundation                 0x1f532795 __CFRunLoopDoSources0
    21 CoreFoundation                 0x1f530a6b __CFRunLoopRun
    22 CoreFoundation                 0x1f480073 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
    23 CoreFoundation                 0x1f47fe81 CFRunLoopRunInMode
    24 GraphicsServices               0x20c2cbfd GSEventRunModal
    25 UIKit                          0x2463482f -[UIApplication _run]
    26 UIKit                          0x2462ef61 UIApplicationMain
    27 Kitapyurdu                     0x222fb main (main.m:16)
    28 libdispatch.dylib              0x1ec4a50b (Missing)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722461/nsinternalinconsistencyexception-reason-could-not-load-nib-in-bundle-nsbun)

Comment: Yeah it maybe, But it didn't satisfy me

Comment: Have you tried accepted answer ?

Comment: No. Because my error occurs rarely. But other one seems continuous. And the accepted answer was given according to this.

Comment: But your log showing the exactly same situation. Other things are up to you. We are here to help you (if you want any).

Comment: How will I be sure that my issue is resolved?

Comment: Firstly, You should say that how I regenarate this crash?

Comment: @Revenge did you register the nib to the tableView before dequeueing the cell with the said nib?

Comment: No. I didn't. Did it is register in viewDidLoad method?

Comment: have you checked line num 429 in ProductToShelfViewController, what is the code there

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in .m file , it's worked for me

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    NSBundle *bundel = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[Yourclassname class]];

    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:bundel];
    if (self) {

        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```