# Could not load NIB in bundle error in storyboard

Tags: ios, crash, storyboard

I am working with storyboards for the first time.

My app is crashing whenever I run the build for very first time where it is downloading all the data from server. It's showing me error in `UIViewController-w6Q-ra-j06` although there is no such file with this name in my project.

Any pointers or help would be appreciated.

```
2013-08-14 15:40:42.967 storeFlix[1614:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle 
</Users/user/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/0AC8F6F7-5B69-4F94-
BCF1-DFE8398AFEFA/storeFlix.app> (loaded)' with name 'UIViewController-w6Q-ra-j06' and 
directory 'StoreFlixIpad.storyboardc''
```

Comment: `Shift+Command+K` helped me.

Comment: i had to remove view controller and add again! than it works

Comment: product->clean, removing and re-adding xib file didn't work for me, Had to delete references from build phases and add again. 
(Xcode 10.0)

Comment: here is working solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/56199366/1371853

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it was **memory issue**. Although I am using **ARC** still I need to manage memory allocation by setting variables to nil.

Answer (score 13):

`Shift+Command+K`

I was getting this error on a fresh (empty) project after creating a storyboard file and setting it as the main interface in the project's settings.... drove me nuts for 15 minutes.

Comment: I had the same problem with brand-new just created project. Clean helped! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Damn, this is still happening in 2016.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>

or

```
Product > Clean
```

This fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware there was a keyboard format available.

Answer (score 3):

There can be many reasons for this particular problem, but first check Target membership and XIB name, as advised here: [Could not load NIB in bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337337/could-not-load-nib-in-bundle)

Check also very carefully if there is any kind of control who's name has changed in header files, but the referencing outlet stayed the same.

Comment: I have seen almost all the questions. It mostly says there is something with that file. But I don't have any such file `UIViewController-w6Q-ra-j06` in y project in which it is showing this error.

Comment: This is internal designation of the file, not the filename itself.

Comment: I've edited my answer. I remember I had a problem and that was the one causing it.

Comment: I have checked that as well. Actually initially it's downloading lot's of data. If I restrict it to 5-10. It's working fine. If I am trying to save all the data it is getting crashed with this crash report.

Comment: Does it work without saving data? What kind of data? Where and how do you save it? Do you persist a managed object? IS there any pointer in such object to your view controller?

Answer (score 2):

What is the name of your storyboard file? Are you loading it programmatically? Or is it specified in your project settings?

See if you used:

`StoreFlixIpad.storyboardc`

instead of:

`StoreFlixIpad.storyboard`

Comment: Yes. It's StoreFlixIpad.storyboard only. And it's working fine also if number of records are less.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I had was that I was instantiating a viewController that was the root controller of a navigation controller. Solution was to just instantiate the navigation controller itself, this will instantly instantiate the root controller too.

Answer (score 1):

Try to re-enter the name of your storyboard in your target general settings. For instance, if your storyboard is `Main.storyboard`, write again `Main.storyboard` in the `Main Interface` field.

Answer (score 1):

What fixes for me after `Product -> Clean Build Folder` is to go to `Target -> General -> Main Interface`

- deselect Main
- select Main again

Here `Main` is your main storyboard name

Comment: Can't upvote this enough...this did it for me (the deselecting / selecting part especially; clean project by itself was not enough).