# exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: ...can someone please find what is wrong with this

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

> error occurs with below code---Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load
>   NIB in bundle:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
                DetailViewController *dvc =[[DetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
                dvc.index = indexPath.row;
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvc  animated:YES];

              }
```

Comment: Is the nib file included in your target (check the file properties pane on the right side of Xcode and make sure the box is checked)?

Comment: mention the name is propabrly, for e.g DetailViewController.xib

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337337/could-not-load-nib-in-bundle

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik where is  DetailViewController.xib file

Comment: its s your xib name , are you used the xib or storyboadr

Comment: @par...how to include nib file...i dont see any file properties and the box

Comment: storyboard....i have file named Main.storyboard ..does that mean i used storyboard right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in your comments you are using Storyboard, then this is not how you will initialize an object of UIViewController with the storyboard.

You must create object like this

```
DetailViewController *vcDetailViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];
vcDetailViewController.index = indexPath.row;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vcDetailViewController  animated:YES];
```

Also, you need to give StoryBoard Id to your view controller, check image

[image]

Comment: I have mentioned that you need to give the storyboard ID to your controller